# The ReactiveUI ver 9.19.5 Binding is not working with Xamarin.Forms ver 4.1.0

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I am trying to get my head around with `ReactiveUI`. I created a new project with the following main packages:

1. Xamarin.Forms 4.1.0.618606
2. PropertyChanged.Fody  3.0.1
3. ReactiveUI 9.19.5
4. ReactiveUI.XamForms 9.19.5

The project have a `page` with associated `viewmodel`. I want to Bind View with the ViewModel using `ReactiveUI`. But the binding does not work. The project build and run but does not fire any `property changed notification` neither any `command`. The app needs to display a `list` of `company names`. But the list does not display the collection defined in `ViewModel` . The app should allows the user the sort the list with `CollectionChangeCommand` with every change in search `query`.

**The View Code :**

```
 <rxui:ReactiveContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                              xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
                              xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                              xmlns:rxui="clr-namespace:ReactiveUI.XamForms;assembly=ReactiveUI.XamForms"
                              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Demo"
                              x:TypeArguments="local:MainViewModel"
                              x:Class="Demo.MainPage">
        <Shell.TitleView>
            <SearchBar x:Name="SearchHandler"
                       Placeholder="SelectCompany" />
        </Shell.TitleView>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="CompaniesListView"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Companies}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                             Margin="10">
                                    <Label x:Name="NameLabel"
                                           Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                </StackLayout>
                                <BoxView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                         HeightRequest="1"
                                         Color="BlueViolet" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <Button Text="ClickMe"
                    x:Name="OnlyButton" />
        </StackLayout>

    </rxui:ReactiveContentPage>
```

**The code behind:**

```
public partial class MainPage : ReactiveContentPage<MainViewModel>
    {
        MainViewModel vm;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Query, v => v.SearchHandler.Text);
            this.BindCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.ButtonClickedCommand, v => v.OnlyButton);

        }
    }
```

**The ViewModel Code:**

```
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
    public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Company> Companies { get; private set; }


        public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> ButtonClickedCommand { get; set; }
        public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> CollectionChange { get; set; }
        public string Query { get; set; }



        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Companies = new ObservableCollection<Company>
            {
                new Company{Name="EPF CORPORATION"},
                new Company{Name="ABC COMPANY PVT. LTD."},
                new Company{Name="UNIQUE COMPUTER SYSTEMS"},
                new Company{Name="MICROSOFT PRIVATE LIMITED"},
            };

            this.WhenAny(x => x.Query, x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Value));
            CollectionChange = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async () => await SortCollection());
            ButtonClickedCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async () => await ButtonClicked()); 

        async Task SortCollection()
        {

            ObservableCollection<Company> temp;
            temp = new ObservableCollection<Company>(Companies.OrderByDescending(m => m.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(Query.ToLower(), StringComparison.CurrentCulture)));
            Companies.Clear();
            foreach (Company c in temp)
                Companies.Add(c);

        }

        async Task ButtonClicked()
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Button Clicked", "The reactive button command fired finally", "OK");
        }
    }
```

I just want to use `ReactiveObject` and`ReactiveCommand`. I will stick with Xamarin.Forms Shell till `ReactiveShell` is not available.

I will be grateful to anyone who can can show me how to use ReactiveUI correctly with xamarin.forms.

Comment: Hey there, you might want to come up with a [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), at the moment it's just a fairly large repository as your example which wouldn't satisfy being minimal.

Comment: @GlennWatson I modified the question. The link to the minimal reproductible project file is https://send.firefox.com/download/11666c7d71103813/#4LiMmwtLS6SHd-VXRM6ohw. The binding works fine with default Xamarin.Forms binding. But not with ReactiveUI. Thank you

Comment: @GlennWatson One more query. How to sort the companies name in ascending order by query string.

Comment: https://github.com/reactiveui/dynamicdata#sorting The sort() extension method just takes in a Comparer, so in your case it could be `Sort(SortExpressionComparer<Company>.Ascending(t => t.Name))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MainPage.xaml.cs you never seem to create the ViewModel?

You are using INotifyPropertyChanged fody on a ReactiveObject, there is a ReactiveUI fody out there. You should not generate mix the INotifyPropertyChange on ReactiveObject's.

You have a `vm` property but that isn't created either.

On `ReactiveContentControl<TViewModel>` it has a property called `ViewModel` which you need to set with something. That can be passed in from another control.

Also in your `ViewModel.cs` file you have a `this.WhenAny` but don't seem to do anything with the observable that is generated?

Be aware also that a better approach for the sorting might be to use the DynamicData framework which is part of the ReactiveUI family now.

You could do something like

ViewModel.cs:

```cs
public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private readonly SourceList<Company> _companies;
    private readonly ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Company> _sortedCompanies;

    //Reactive Commands
    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> ButtonClickedCommand { get; }

    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Company> Companies => _sortedCompanies;

    [Reactive]
    public string Query { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _companies = new SourceList<Company>();
        _companies.AddRange(new[]
        {
            new Company{Name="EPF CORPORATION"},
            new Company{Name="ABC COMPANY PVT. LTD."},
            new Company{Name="UNIQUE COMPUTER SYSTEMS"},
            new Company{Name="MICROSOFT PRIVATE LIMITED"},
        });

        // Delay to once every 500 milliseconds doing an update.
        var refreshObs = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Query).Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

        _companies.Connect()
            .AutoRefreshOnObservable(_ => refreshObs)
            .Filter(m => Query == null || m.Name.IndexOf(Query, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0) // If it contains a portion of the text.
            .Sort(SortExpressionComparer<Company>.Ascending(t => t.Name))
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .Bind(out _sortedCompanies)
            .Subscribe();

        ButtonClickedCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async () => await ButtonClicked());
    }

    async Task ButtonClicked()
    {
        await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Button Clicked", "The reactive button command fired finally", "OK");
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ReactiveContentPage<MainViewModel>
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ViewModel = new MainViewModel();

        //ReactiveUI Bindings
        this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Query, v => v.SearchHandler.Text);
        this.BindCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.ButtonClickedCommand, v => v.OnlyButton);

        this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Companies, view => view.CompaniesListView.ItemsSource);
    }
}
```

I added the ReactiveUI.Fody package included `ReactiveUI` in the FodyWeavers.xml

Also I changed your ListView to not do the XAML binding so `<ListView x:Name="CompaniesListView">`

This seems to be working well for me.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The support by experts like you is very helpful for onboarding beginners like me.

Comment: Added the sort expression to the example to match your original example (as per your comment on the main question).